# How can I remove '...' in an iPhone dropdown list with CSS?

Tags: iphone, css

How can I remove '...' in an iPhone dropdown list with CSS?
Is it possible? Or change a font's size?

[image]

Comment: Font size is too big. You will not be able to remove the "...":d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your strings is too long. You may make them shorter, or make text font smaller, or override this class to make text label bigger. this "..." are automatic, and you cant just remove it.

Comment: Yeah. Right. But what css class I have to override?

Comment: not shure about this. you may also try to add UILabel to cells, insteed of useing usuals